# Is there a CSS tool / language / syntax to simplify "-moz" "-webkit" "-ms" "-o" statements compatibility?

Tags: html, css

This is an example code with many compatibility versions:

```
.shake {
  background-color: #2bd993;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 30px 0 0;
  padding: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.shake:hover {
  animation: shake 150ms 2 linear;
  -moz-animation: shake 150ms 2 linear;
  -webkit-animation: shake 150ms 2 linear;
  -o-animation: shake 150ms 2 linear;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: translate(3px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes shake {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate(3px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: translate(-3px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(3px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes shake {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: translate(3px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-3px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes shake {
  0% {
    -o-transform: translate(3px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    -o-transform: translate(-3px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

Are there CSS languages / syntax / tips to write less code while maximizing retrocompatibility ?

The best I have achieved so far was with the use of CSS variables, but I wonder if we can simplify further.

Comment: Does your site/product have enough visitors using outdated browsers that you need to worry about vendor-prefixes at this point? Also, why do you want to "*avoid writing less code*," isn't "less code" the goal?

Comment: "avoid writing less code" was a typo, I corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would use [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) or the like you could add an [Autoprefixer](https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/5625786-produce-maintainable-css-with-sass/5725186-use-autoprefixer-for-browser-compliant-code), you can also check https://caniuse.com/ and see if it is still necessary to add the prefixes